# Should static pages have access to cookies in rails controller and routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm sure this is an obvious question but I just don't understand why this isn't working.

I'm finding that my static pages defined in the `routes.rb` file don't seem to have access to cookies? Is that correct? I'm trying to read the value of a cookie but the pages below seem to return a null object.

My routes.rb contains the following:

```
scope controller: :static do
  get :about
  get :terms
  get :privacy
  get :cookies
  get :returns
  get :delivery
end
```

For completeness here is the `Static Controller`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class StaticController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_order

  def index; end

  def about; end

  def pricing
    redirect_to root_path, alert: t('.no_plans') unless Plan.without_free.exists?
  end

  def terms; end

  def privacy; end

  def cookies; end

  def returns; end

  def delivery; end
end
```

And this is how the cookie is set:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_order

def add_hamper
    @order ||= Order.create!(
      ordernum: find_next_order_number,
      user: current_user,
      basket: true
    )
    @order.hampers << Hamper.friendly.find(params[:id])
    update_order_total(@order)
    if current_user&.custaddress
      @order.update(custaddress: current_user.custaddress)
    else
      cookies[:ordernum] = @order.ordernum
    end

    redirect_to order_path(@order.ordernum)
    # Update basket in Navbar
    # Save the information as a cookie reference if they are not signed in
  end
```

At the start of each controller I have a `before_action` to find an order if it exists in the DB or Cookie. For all other controllers, the `find_order` method is working. For the StaticController, there seems to be no access to the cookies.

Here is my `find_order` as defined in `ApplicationController`:

```
def find_order
  @order = if current_user
             Order.where(
               user: current_user,
               basket: true
             ).first
           else
             if cookies.dig[:ordernum]
               Order.where(
                 ordernum: cookies[:ordernum],
                 basket: true
               ).first
             end
           end
end
helper_method :find_order
```

I've had to add the check for `cookies` and then `if cookies[:ordernum]` to stop it from failing on the static pages.

Thanks for any help with this.

PS. If anyone feels the above code could be better ... please let me know! There must be a nicer way to achieve this. It feels a little clunky.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can do `if cookies.dig[:ordernum]` instead of two `if` statements

Comment: Thanks @Eyeslandic. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Just to check: Is static_controller.rb inheriting from Application Controller?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that I checked that it was inheriting from Application Controller. @JohnAthayde

Comment: To Rails there is absolutely no difference between "static pages" and any other controller/route. So the answer is *yes*, this should work. How are you setting the cookie? And how are testing this?

Comment: @max I have added into the question where the cookie is being set. All other controllers appear to be able to see and utilise the cookie. It's just the ones in the static route.